# Fragment has target not in Fragment Manager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android programming.

I just try to save the state of the `ListView` in my fragment. For that I follow headless fragments (fragment which has no UI). In this fragment, I save the data, used in the `ListView`, and starting the headless fragment from the main fragment (the one which has the UI).

Now I got the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: RetainedFragment{4161f850 #1 work} has target not in fragment manager: JobOpeningFramgent{41601c00}
```

As far my concern, this is happening when I'm trying to replace the fragments with another one in the `DrawerLayout`.

Please temme the cause of this exception, for better understanding.

Thanks.

Boopathy.

Comment: Post Your code.I suppose that you have a class that extends Fragment and an other static inner class that extends Fragment with setRetainInstance(true) !!
Then you call innerClass.setTargetFragment.
When The outer Fragment is Destroyed what happens? 
the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround:

put this in the fragment that causes the problems:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
    setTargetFragment(null, -1);
            ...
```

and remember to set it to the real target fragment when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to save and where do you want to save it.

The official docs state that: ["A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity."](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Using a `Fragment` as a container of another Fragment's UI state is generally a bad idea.

If you want to persist some values throughout the activity lifecycle (that includes screen rotations) just override `onSaveInstanceState` method. If you want to store some variables even after activity life-time use singelton class or `Preferences`, and if you want to store your values even after app life-time use `SharedPreferences`

Please elaborate on what do you exacly want

Comment: I retrieve data from the network. During the configuration change, the fragment and corresponding activity is undergo the life-cycle. So it is again loading from the network. Rather, I follow this [article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html), and saved the values in headless fragments. Now I'm getting the above exception. Hope I'm clear now!!!